# Javascript Create and Update Record In Dynamics CRM from Custom Button

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a requirement to create and update some records from custom button. This custom button placed on homepage of the contact. First, i need to check one or more contact. Once the custom button is clicked, its creating an account in account entity then update look up field of the contact that i checked before with account that we create.

I am trying the step inside this [link](http://www.zacrmguy.com/js-crud-operations-with-web-api-in-crm-2016/#comment-447) and [this](https://lakshmanindian.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/update-selected-records-in-home-page-entity-grid-in-crm-2011/), but it's seem doesn't work for Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premis

Could you please help me and give me a suggestion or another documentary that you think it can satisfy my requirement above.

**EDITED**:
on the sdk, there is an example to use JQueryRestDataOperation. From there, i write a code like this:

```
    function createAccount() {

 startButton.attr("name");

 var account = {};

 account.Name = "Test Account Name";

 account.Description = "This account was created by the JQueryRESTDataOperations sample.";



 //Create the Account

 SDK.JQuery.createRecord(

     account,

     "account",

     function (account) {

      writeMessage("The account named "" + account.Name + "" was created with the AccountId : "" + account.AccountId + "".");

      writeMessage("Retrieving account with the AccountId: "" + account.AccountId + "".");

      retrieveAccount(account.AccountId)

     },

     errorHandler

   );



}
```

I add this code as webresource in my solution, then call it from custom button. But nothing happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create Account you can use code given below. On click of button give call to function CreateAccount()

```js
function CreateAccount() { 
    var accountId, accountName;
    var context = Xrm.Page.context; 
    var serverUrl = context.getServerUrl(); 
    var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"; 
    var CRMObject = new Object(); 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // Specify the ODATA entity collection 
    var ODATA_EntityCollection = "/AccountSet"; 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // Define attribute values for the CRM object you want created 
    CRMObject.Name = "TEST";
    accountName = "TEST"; 
    CRMObject.Telephone1 = "123"; 
    CRMObject.Fax = "456"; 
    //Parse the entity object into JSON 
    var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(CRMObject); 
    //Asynchronous AJAX function to Create a CRM record using OData 
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        datatype: "json", 
        url: serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + ODATA_EntityCollection, 
        data: jsonEntity, 
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { 
            //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON. 
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
        }, 
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) { 
            alert("success"); 
            var NewCRMRecordCreated = data["d"]; 
            accountId = NewCRMRecordCreated.AccountId;
            UpdateContact(accountId,accountName); 
        }, 
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("failure"); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

To Uppdate contact

```js
function UpdateContact(accountId, accountName) {
    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl().toString();
    var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
    var ODATA_EntityCollection = "/AccountSet";

    var objContact = new Object();
    // set the name of Account
    objContact.Id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

    // set the Primary Contact lookup field
    objContact.AccoutId = { Id: accountId, LogicalName: "account", Name: accountName };

    // Parse the entity object into JSON 
    var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(objContact);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + ODATA_EntityCollection,
        data: jsonEntity,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response.d != null) {
                alert(response.d.ContactId);
            }
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus + "; ErrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code. One question. What .js files that you add for webreference ? I just add jquery.1.9.1 and sdk.jquery. Is there any js file that missing from my webresource ?

Comment: I dont know whats wrong here, but your code is not working. I think there is requirement that i missing

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code using F12? If yes then please let me know as this code is working fine for me.

Comment: Hii @meet, you re code is run after i change `getServerUrl`  to  `getClientUrl`